# localStorage is not working if a page is already open

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have created a Google Chrome extension which fetches business information from a business' details page and it fetches city, state and postal codes using the business' address with the help of Google's geocoding API. I am storing the values of city, state and pin using `localStorage` like below:

```js
var city = "", state = "", pin = "";
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+encodeURIComponent(laddress[1].replace(/<.*?>/g,'').replace('&amp;','&').trim())+"&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCAQmrAKh0jzNVcT1VqTUhjB5Oh_dxl1zA";
console.log(url);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var resp;
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "*/*");
xhr.onload = function () {
    var json = xhr.responseText;                         // Response
    json = json.replace(/^[^(]*\(([\S\s]+)\);?$/, '$1'); // Turn JSONP in JSON
    json = JSON.parse(json);  
    console.log(json.results[0].address_components);
    for(var i=0;i<json.results[0].address_components.length;i++){
        if(json.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]=="administrative_area_level_2")
            city = json.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        if(json.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1")
            state = json.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        if(json.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]=="postal_code")
            pin = json.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("city", city);
    localStorage.setItem("state", state);
    localStorage.setItem("pin", pin);
}
xhr.send();
lcity = localStorage.getItem("city");
lstate = localStorage.getItem("state");
lpin = localStorage.getItem("pin");
```

Problems arises when

- the business page is already opened and I try to click the extension, localStorage won't work
- sometimes, it doesn't show any value, sometimes it shows up values.

What should I do to get perfect values in `localStorage` while accessing multiple business pages?

Comment: Your situation is equivalent to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call - you are trying to use the value before it's set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're using the wrong localStorage. While localStorage is defined as per HTML5, it needs a rooted context like wwww.something.com.

Try using [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

To modify an example from the documents. Let's use the local storage.

```
var city = "", state = "", pin = "";
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+encodeURIComponent(laddress[1].replace(/<.*?>/g,'').replace('&amp;','&').trim())+"&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCAQmrAKh0jzNVcT1VqTUhjB5Oh_dxl1zA";
console.log(url);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var resp;
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "*/*");
xhr.onload = function () {
    var json = xhr.responseText;     // Response
    json = json.replace(/^[^(]*\(([\S\s]+)\);?$/, '$1'); // Turn JSONP in JSON
    json = JSON.parse(json);  
    console.log(json.results[0].address_components);
    for(var i=0;i<json.results[0].address_components.length;i++){       
        if(json.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]=="administrative_area_level_2")
            city = json.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        if(json.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1")
            state = json.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        if(json.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]=="postal_code")
            pin = json.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
    }
    chrome.storage.local.set({“city”: city,
                    "state”: state,
                    "pin”: pin}, function(){
                    // Do stuff here after set.
                    chrome.storage.local.get(["city", "state", "pin",
                        function(items) {
                            lcity = items.city;
                            lstate = items.state;
                            lpin = items.pin;
                        }
                });
}
xhr.send();
```

Please remember to modify your permissions in the manifest to use storage.

**A Quick Point:** xhr.send() is an async call. Setting the l*variables right after is your problem with data some times showing. Handle that in unload or local.set callback. The example above has the setting in the callback.